Shall l agree to repairs or return car?
I would be really grateful if I could get some suggestions on an issue I'm having at the moment.
I bought a 2015 Vauxhall 1.4 petrol engine that had covered 63k miles when I bought it. It had a clean MOT history here in the UK. While driving the car away from dealer, an engine light popped up. Dealer ran a diagnostic and there was a problem with cam shaft position sensor. He "fixed" it a few days later and I took the car back.
After a week, the car stalled on the middle of the road. Took the car to nearby garage and was told timing chain is on its way out and there was a coolant leak as well from coolant flange, that needs replacing too.
I talked to the dealer and they have agreed to repairs, but I am hesitant to go ahead with the repairs as I am not happy with the car and how it has been causing one problem or another since I've had it. I have had it for 14 days now. Another concern is it was advertised as having a full service history but they haven't been able to provide me with the relevant service documents.
With the age and mileage of the car considered and the willingness of the dealer to cover repairs, should I accept the repairs, or are these problems sure to cause further issues down the line in future?
Thank you.

You wrote:

[I]t was advertised as having a full service history but they haven't
been able to provide me with the relevant service documents.

More likely the dealer had full access to service documents but was unwilling to provide them for fear that it would scare you away and spoil the deal.
If you are able to return the car, return it asap and be glad that the problems arose so early in your ownership. If you have "lemon laws" in the UK, read up on them. If your sales contract provides for returning the car for cause, read the clauses carefully and understand them before you approach the dealer.
If they give you a hard time, stand firm and make them provide service documents as advertised or threaten to report them to the government ministry that prosecutes false advertising. And if they can produce them and there is a history of unusual troubles with the car, you could tell them that you consider the sales contract null and void because they failed to disclose relevant details about the car.
Just my opinion (and you know what they say about opinions), but with all the used cars to choose from, there's no reason that you have to be stuck with a lemon.

Thank you MTA.
I am having a pretty hard time in choosing used cars. The one I bought before this had a blown head gasket which I had to sell for huge loss. Now this :/

@GajendraKc No offense intended, but maybe you are being too passive / too submissive with used car dealers. Like signing on the dotted line and plopping down your money without the service history as advertised, and accepting a lame excuse. Remember that it's your hard earned money, they want it and you are in charge. No one can take advantage of you without your permission. Do not succumb to aggressive sales tactics and above all do not allow them to make you believe that they are doing you a favor by selling you the car when the opposite is true.

None taken. You are absolutely right. I'm easily bullied/manipulated. Has been my problem for some time now.

@GajendraKc Then you may benefit from a service offered by several UK firms (such as carhounds.co.uk) that serve as a concierge used car buying service. They negotiate price and terms, they eliminate the buyer's contact with the dealer and they can arrange for an independent inspection before purchase. All this service comes at a price, but consider the cost of succumbing to aggressive dealer sales tactics that lead you to buy a lemon.
